# Sequence contains no matching element error on file upload

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen, and I am using the REST API to upload a file. This was working correctly, but after the upgrade to 21.203.0030, it stopped working (error included below).

I have been trying various things such as re-creating the web service endpoint from scratch etc, but no luck.

It seems that Acumatica manages to add the file to the the UploadFile database table, but it is not being added to NoteDoc (which I believe acts as the link between the screen and the attachments)

Would anyone have any suggestions on what I could try?

ERROR:

> System.ApplicationException: File Upload - {"message":"An error has
> occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Sequence contains no matching
> element","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
> predicate)\r\n at
> PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.PutFile(EntityImpl
> entityImpl, String filename, HttpContent body)\r\n at
> PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.PutFile(String
> objectName, String ids)\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object ,
> Object[] )\r\n at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object
> instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
> controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
> where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown

Comment: What is the code?

Comment: Nothing special, I even replicate in postman. Just standard url to upload file: http://cbar21R2/entity/MyEndpoint/20.200.001/MyObject/111/files/myfile.txt I added Accept application/json as the Request Header. Some text in the body to represent the file contents ... and that's all

Comment: This is not how S.O. works. Please read the guidelines in order how to ask. You need to help us in order we help you. We need code for debugging.